# Invalid symbolic link to python3 when launching Kivy iOS app on simulator Xcode 11.5

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy

The build of my kivy app for iOS was successful but it cannot launch due to the following error:

> This app could not be installed at this time. Domain:
>   IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code: 1 Failure Reason: Could not install
>   at this time. Recovery Suggestion: invalid symlink at
>   /Users/martinprater/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FC5C2E10-9FBA-4E67-A8D5-4F70046A3C51/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.agEl8q/extracted/stopwining.app/YourApp/bin/python3

The directory contains to links:
python -> python3
python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

Surprisingly I can build and run a trivial kivy app without any issues.
I have tried: 
- rebuilding the cache
- reinstalling Xcode (11.5)
- rebuilding the simulators
- cleaning the build
- overriding the symbolic links (this is always reverted as soon as a rebuild)

None of this has shown any effect.
Any help warmly appreciated.

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding python3 and kivy with kivy-ios toolchain solved the issue.

```
toolchain.py build python3
toolchain.py build kivy
```